# How do I set the correct transaction level?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, dapper, isolation-level

I am using Dapper on ADO.NET. So at present I am doing the following:

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString")))
{
conn.Open());
using (IDbTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
// ...
```

However, there are various levels of transactions that can be set. [I think this is the various settings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.isolationlevel?view=netframework-1.1)

My first question is how do I set the transaction level (where I am using Dapper)?

My second question is what is the correct level for each of the following cases? In each of these cases we have multiple instances of a web worker (Azure) service running that will be hitting the DB at the same time.

1. I need to run monthly charges on subscriptions. So in a transaction I need to read a record and if it's due for a charge create the invoice record and mark the record as processed. Any other read of that record for the same purpose needs to fail. But any other reads of that record that are just using it to verify that it is active need to succeed.

So what transaction do I use for the access that will be updating the processed column? And what transaction do I use for the other access that just needs to verify that the record is active?

In this case it's fine if a conflict causes the charge to not be run (we'll get it the next day). But it is critical that we not charge someone twice. And it is critical that the read to verify that the record is active succeed immediately while the other operation is in its transaction.

2. I need to update a record where I am setting just a couple of columns. One use case is I set a new password hash for a user record. It's fine if other access occurs during this except for deleting the record (I think that's the only problem use case). If another web service is also updating that's the user's problem for doing this in 2 places simultaneously.

But it's key that the record stay consistent. And this includes the use case of "set NumUses = NumUses + @ParamNum" so it needs to treat the read, calculation, write of the column value as an atomic action. And if I am setting 3 column values, they all get written together.

Comment: How many invoicing jobs do you run at once? Can you not simply stop others from starting, while one is running?

Comment: To answer your question about transaction types: there is no transaction type that allows you to grant "selective" access to data. You will need to code this mechanism yourself.

Comment: Please elaborate on case 2. I am confused regarding deleting and updating records at the same time. Maybe some code sample will help.

Comment: @Alex 1) I set it so that only 1 service is running the invoicing. But they way cloud services work on Azure, when it flips to a different server, you can have the service running on 2 servers for a bit. 2) I don't think this is selective access, it's just not executing the second select until after the first transaction completes. Or throws an exception or returns nothing. 3) What if in this case, as I am updating a record, another service deletes that record? What happens then?

Answer (score 1):

1) Assuming that Invoicing process is an SP with multiple statements your best bet is to create another "lock" table to store the fact that invoicing job is already running e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE InvoicingJob( JobStarted DATETIME, IsRunning BIT NOT NULL )

-- Table will only ever have one record
INSERT INTO InvoicingJob
SELECT NULL, 0


EXEC InvoicingProcess

ALTER PROCEDURE InvoicingProcess
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @InvoicingJob TABLE( IsRunning BIT )

    -- Try to aquire lock
    UPDATE InvoicingJob WITH( TABLOCK )
    SET JobStarted = GETDATE(), IsRunning = 1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.IsRunning INTO @InvoicingJob( IsRunning )
    WHERE IsRunning = 0
        -- job has been running for more than a day i.e. likely crashed without releasing a lock
        -- OR ( IsRunning = 1 AND JobStarted <= DATEADD( DAY, -1, GETDATE()) 

    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @InvoicingJob )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Another Job is already running'
        RETURN
    END
    ELSE
        RAISERROR( 'Start Job', 0, 0 ) WITH NOWAIT


    -- Do invoicing tasks
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00' -- to simulate execution time

    -- Release lock
    UPDATE InvoicingJob
    SET IsRunning = 0
END
```

2) Read about how transactions work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You second question is quite broad.